# Is SuperSU still downloadable anywhere or is the project dead?

Tags: rooting, supersu

I am trying to root an Asus Tinkerboard and I've come across some instructions that mention downloading the flashable zips from the [SuperSu.com downloads page](http://www.supersu.com/download). However it seems all of these links on the page are dead now, possibly pointing to files hosted on AWS that no longer exist.

Does anyone know if there is a new place where these might be hosted so that I can download them? In researching a bit I've come to understand that chainfire parted ways with them early this year but seems to indicate that the project would live on in his absence. It's been several months now did it end up not really living on as anticipated? Has it just moved elsewhere? Is it just a temporary issue? I checked throughout the weekend and they've been dead links the whole time so I don't think it's temporary, but only been looking a few days.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I know that the Chinese company Chainfire passed SuperSU to, was purported as a company of proved experience, and yet no proof of this experience existed.

Comment: We have seen nothing from the company Chainfire sold SuperSU to, and he has ended all root development https://plus.google.com/+Chainfire/posts/ZVDG2SnmgM5 there has been some speculation that this was merely a corporate conspiracy to end rooting (which failed) but the SuperSU project is essentially dead.

Comment: See; https://www.supersubeta.com and their [blog](http://blog.supersubeta.com)